# transmission-daemon service log to file error: sendto: Operation not permitted

Tags: transmission

I am running transmission-daemon as a systemd service.

```
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -e <path>
```

where I have tried different values for path all with universal write permissions. The log file is successfully created but it is empty.

`systemctl status`  reports

```
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip systemd[1]: Started Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip transmission-daemon[1207119]: sendto: Operation not permitted
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip transmission-daemon[1207119]: sendto: Operation not permitted
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip transmission-daemon[1207119]: sendto: Operation not permitted
 Nov 18 07:39:48 flip transmission-daemon[1207119]: sendto: Operation not permitted
```

requested by @binarysta

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=transmission
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -e /mnt/ram/log/transmission-daemon.log
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: can you disable `SELinux` and try again? and please add the whole `systemd` service config file to the question.

Comment: @binarysta Thanks. SELinux is not enabled or installed. Which service file are you looking for?

Comment: the systemd service of transmission

Comment: @binarysta added. However the log is working now. I ran a general update and a reboot. Now I see a problem for another question.